# Finding causal Inference from sentiment analysis

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference, causality

I am conducting a sentiment analysis on thousands of social media posts by unemployed manufacturing workers to see how online sentiment of the group members I am analyzing has changed after an announcement of an economic policy program aimed at helping that group. Specifically, I am interested in moving beyond descriptive statistics of sentiment analysis, towards measuring whether there is a causal relationship between the feelings/sentiment of the group behavior online, before and after the policy's introduction.

A sample of the dataset is shown below:

```
date
<S3: POSIXct>
sentiment
<chr>
year
<dbl>
treatment_implementation
<chr>
2011-12-01  neutral     2011    pre
2011-12-01  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-01  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-03  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-03  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-04  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-07  negative    2011    pre
2011-12-15  positive    2011    post
2011-12-20  positive    2011    post
2011-12-20  positive    2011    post
2011-12-22  positive    2011    post
2011-12-23  positive    2011    post
2011-12-27  positive    2011    post
2011-12-27  positive    2011    post
```

What methods can I use to measure whether there is a causal relationship between my binary outcome variable: positive/negative sentiment, and the introduction of a government program aimed directly to support the group of jobless manufacturing workers.

Is it possible to use logistic or multinomial regression in this case?

Comment: You might consider regression discontinuity designs (RDD) or interrupted time series.

Comment: Mind elaborating further on how RDD applies here?
I have used the method a lot in the past, but only in policy impact evaluation, where the threshold is clear such as: 1- household income or 2-SAT exam score, for instance.

Comment: You could consider time to be the thresholding variable. If the effect is not immediate in time then it might not be the way to go.

Comment: Good idea, what if the outcome varies post-treatment? So let's say sentiment is mostly positive, but there are also negative posts, I assume RDD would not be effective in that case, correct?